# List is not getting displayed in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

This is my code:

```
var tablepnl = Ext.define('TablePanel', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
                config: {
                fullscreen: true,
                        layout: 'fit',
                        items: [{
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                                docked: 'top',
                                height: 40,
                                title: 'Table Allocation',
                                items: [{some items}]
                                }, {
                        xtype: 'list',
                                store: tableAllocationStore,
                                itemTpl: tableTpl,
                                grouped: true,
                                pinHeaders: false,
                                listeners: {
                                itemsingletap: function (index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
                                //code
                                }
                                }
                        },
                        {
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                                docked: 'bottom',
                                height: 40,
                                title: 'xyz'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                constructor: function (config) {
                this.callParent(config);
                        this.initConfig(config);
                }
        });
        Ext.create('TablePanel');
}
});
```

Code is showing bottom and top title bar but list is not getting displayed. help guys

I have tried this but not working for me: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?161490-List-not-showing

Comment: Please check that your `tableAllocationStore` contains entries. My best guess is that your list is there, but the store is empty, thus the screen is blank. If you can rule out that the store is empty, please [make a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home).

Comment: even if i try to give default data to list still its not displaying anything.

Comment: Your code isn't complete - what is tableAllocationStore, what is tableTpl. Any, by the way: MAKE A FIDDLE!

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1d0a   my fiddle link. thank u Alexander for ur time

Answer (score 0):

There is just a version issue, in your fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1d0a) you are using 2.1.1 please try using version 2.2.* your code will work.

Comment: For me it doesn't, the list is still blank in 2.2.1 and even 2.3.1. It works in 2.4.2, though.

Comment: yeah changed the version and list gets displayed.. thanks all for the help.

Comment: displayed in version 2.4.2 and 2.0.1.1